# How do I replace submitHandler by success.form.bv?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to adapt the JS code below from my contact form to make it compatible with bootstrapvalidator >0.5

According to [this site](http://xdsoft.net/jquery-plugins/bootstrapvalidator/) I need to replace submitHandler by success.form.bv

Could you please help me to do this?

Many thanks,

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#contact_form').bootstrapValidator({
        // To use feedback icons, ensure that you use Bootstrap v3.1.0 or later
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'fa fa-check',
            invalid: 'fa fa-times',
            validating: 'fa fa-refresh'
        },
  submitHandler: function (validator, form, submitButton) {
          $('button[name="submit"]').hide();

          var bv = form.data('bootstrapValidator');
          // Use Ajax to submit form data
          $.post(form.attr('action'), form.serialize(), function (result) {
              if (result.status == 1) {
                  $('#success_message').slideDown({
                      opacity: "show"
                  }, "slow")
                  $('#contact_form').data('bootstrapValidator').resetForm();
              } else {
                    $('#error_message').slideDown({
                      opacity: "show"
                  }, "slow")              }
          }, 'json');
      },
        fields: {
            first_name: {
                validators: {
                        stringLength: {
                        min: 2,
                    },
                        notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Veuillez indiquer votre prénom'
                    }
                }
            },
             last_name: {
                validators: {
                     stringLength: {
                        min: 2,
                    },
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Veuillez indiquer votre nom'
                    }
                }
            },
            email: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Veuillez indiquer votre adresse e-mail'
                    },
                    emailAddress: {
                        message: 'Veuillez indiquer une adresse e-mail valide'
                    }
                }
            },
            message: {
                validators: {
                      stringLength: {
                        min: 10,
                        max: 1000,
                        message:'Votre message doit faire plus de 10 caractères et moins de 1000.'
                    },
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Veuillez indiquer votre message'
                    }
                    }
                }
            }
        })

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#contact_form').bootstrapValidator({
            // To use feedback icons, ensure that you use Bootstrap v3.1.0 or later
            feedbackIcons: {
                valid: 'fa fa-check',
                invalid: 'fa fa-times',
                validating: 'fa fa-refresh'
            },
            fields: {
                first_name: {
                    validators: {
                            stringLength: {
                            min: 2,
                        },
                            notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Veuillez indiquer votre prénom'
                        }
                    }
                },
                 last_name: {
                    validators: {
                         stringLength: {
                            min: 2,
                        },
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Veuillez indiquer votre nom'
                        }
                    }
                },
                email: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Veuillez indiquer votre adresse e-mail'
                        },
                        emailAddress: {
                            message: 'Veuillez indiquer une adresse e-mail valide'
                        }
                    }
                },
                message: {
                    validators: {
                          stringLength: {
                            min: 10,
                            max: 1000,
                            message:'Votre message doit faire plus de 10 caractères et moins de 1000.'
                        },
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Veuillez indiquer votre message'
                        }
                        }
                    }
                }}).on('success.form.bv', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
              $('button[name="submit"]').hide();

              var bv = $(this).data('bootstrapValidator');
              // Use Ajax to submit form data
              $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function (result) {
                  if (result.status == 1) {
                      $('#success_message').slideDown({
                          opacity: "show"
                      }, "slow")
                      $('#contact_form').data('bootstrapValidator').resetForm();
                  } else {
                        $('#error_message').slideDown({
                          opacity: "show"
                      }, "slow")              }
              }, 'json');
          }
            );

    });
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it does not seem to be working (the ok/not ok messages and icons that are supposed to show up while I'm typing are not showing up at all)

Comment: Madalin, one more question if I may: I'd like to apply a different class to my submit button if the validation steps are successful (for instance the button would have a grey background by default, and then turn to a green background once all the fields have passed the validation checks. How can I control this through your JS code?
FYI here is my submit button (we could have something like "submit-button" and "submit-button ok" (class "OK" would change the background color): <button class="submit-button" name="submit" type="submit">

Comment: in the `success.form.bv ` or in the success function of the ajax you do `$('.submit-button').addClass('ok');`

Comment: Thanks. Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/r2y1bq2g/ But it means the "ok" class is applied after the button disappears, correct?

Comment: from what i can tell you remove the button so the ok class is irrelevant here better go with a message that tells the use that the form was submited

Comment: Thanks for your help